# Get Edge version when run via Azure RemoteApp

Tags: microsoft-edge, remoteapp

For testing purposes I run Edge via the Azure RemoteApp. How can I check which Edge version (Engine, HTML) is run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the official page:

> **Why can't I use a remote version of Microsoft Edge?**
>
> *Due to RemoteApp limitations, we aren't currently able to offer a remote version of Microsoft Edge. Instead, RemoteIE loads a recent
>   version of the EdgeHTML rendering engine inside Internet Explorer.
>   We're working on adding a remote version of Microsoft Edge in the
>   future.*

*Source*: https://dev.windows.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/remote/

In case this information is outdated, I've also reached out to the Edge team via Twitter, so keep an eye on this tweet:

- https://twitter.com/shahedC/status/702303693140393984

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't answer my question concerning the versions.

Comment: Understood, I was just pointing out that it's not actually Edge, which was just confirmed by Patrick (Edge team) in another answer. It is IE with the Edge engine. If you do want to know the engine's version number, you could use the usual practice of detecting the User Agent string. But I would highly recommend against using this UA information to write any browser-specific JavaScript code (in case you or your team were thinking about it). Instead, check for browser capabilities if needed.

Answer (score 0):

I work on Edge at Microsoft.
Shashed is correct. The answer is "it is not Edge". It is IE 11, with a switched out rendering engine (the old trident engine for the new Edge engine).

If you want to know which version of the Edge engine is being run, its as simple as checking the user agent string. As of today (02/24/2016), it is

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36 Edge/12.10514
```

Note the `Edge/12.10514`, that means it is Edge v12. The current shipping version on Windows 10 is Edge 13 (note there has been [some confusion on Edge's versions](https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2015/09/21/understanding-versions-in-an-evergreen-browser/) previously).

Comment: Thanks for the information. So it seems to be a pretty old Edge version. I'm interested in developing an Edge extension as soon as extensions are supported. Is there any possibility to install/test the latest Edge versions which are included in the Windows Insider fast ring without being a Windows Insider?

Comment: there have only been two major versions of Edge released, this was the first. In order to access content on the Windows Insider fast ring you will need to access the fast ring. If you don't want to do so on your main machine, you can perhaps use a virtual machine to do so.

Comment: [Here](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/remote/#about-remote) is a statement that the hosted version will be updated in sync with the Windows Insider Releases. This seems not to be the case, because the version is still "Edge/12.10514". Any idea when this will be updated? I'd like to test extensions which were released yesterday in Insider Preview Build 14291.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply open the F12 Developer Tools, go to console and type `navigator.userAgent` to get the UA string. See the screenshot:

[image]

As the other guys already mentioned you could also [download a free VM](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/windows/) to test with a more current version of MS Edge.